# Sublime3 - cannot find file specified when executing python script in Windows

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3

I am trying to setup Sublime3 on Windows 10 Enterprise edition to execute a python script using Tools>Build.

Its a simple hello_world.py script.

Here's my output:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\PBC9390\\Desktop\\python_work\\hello_world.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\PBC9390\Desktop\python_work]
[path: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\EHLLAPI\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Hitachi ID\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Hitachi ID\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\;;C:\hashiCorp\Terraform;C:\Program Files (x86)\Webex\Webex\Applications;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\PBC9390\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\PBC9390\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin]
```

Here's my **Python3.sublime-build** file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

Is this the problem? I'm not sure how its being converted with double backslash "\":

```
'C:\\Users\\PBC9390\\Desktop\\python_work\\hello_world.py'
```

Comment: Is `python3.exe` available inside of one of those folders shown in your `PATH`? If you open a command console and enter `where python3`, what does it say? The doubling of the slashes is part of the debug output because the \ character is special in Python strings.

Comment: thanks, the output of that command is pointing to here: *C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe* - I don't see the .exe in the path, but the folder is the path: C:\Program Files\Python37\. Is that the problem? i don't have admin privileges to set make changes to environment variables.